# Python flask jinja2 template variable contexts. Can't render variables

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, jinja2

EDIT: Simplified the for loop to make it easier to illustrate the problem but the issue is still the same.

I'm trying to get render a flask jinja2 template to render a carousel of images from a list of image names. The images variable is showing up in my debugger and it looks like it's looping through when I step through it but for some reason it's not rendering.

```
# flask app file
@app.route('/results', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
@login_required
def newpage(page=1):
    """
    Renders search page
    """
    form = genus_form()
    user = current_user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if form.validate_on_submit():
            gen = Genus.query.filter(Genus.genus_name.like(form.genus.data)).first()
            spec = Species.query.filter_by(GID=gen.GID).first()
            images = Images.query.filter_by(UID=spec.UID).all()
            if images:
                images = [i.FileName for i in images]
            form.genus.data = ''
            render_template('results.html', form=form, images=images)
        else:
            return render_template('results.html', form=form)
    return render_template('results.html', form=form)
```

Here is the relevant section from the jinja template:

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% block title %} WCTC Image Review {% endblock %}
{% block scripts %}
    {{ super() }}
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#genus").autocomplete({
        delay: 100,
        source: function (request, response) {

            // Suggest URL
            var suggestURL = "{{ url_for('autocomplete') }}?term=%QUERY";
            suggestURL = suggestURL.replace('%QUERY', request.term);

            // JSON Request
            $.ajax({
                method: 'GET',
                dataType: 'json',
                jsonCallback: 'jsonCallback',
                url: suggestURL
            })
            .success(function(data){
                response(data);
            });
        }
    });
});

$('#myCarousel').carousel({
  interval: 40000
});

$('.carousel .item').each(function(){
  var next = $(this).next();
  if (!next.length) {
    next = $(this).siblings(':first');
  }
  next.children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  if (next.next().length>0) {
      next.next().children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this)).addClass('rightest');

  }
  else {
      $(this).siblings(':first').children(':first-child').clone().appendTo($(this));

  }
});

</script>
{% endblock %}
{% block content %}

<div>
    <form action="/results" method="POST" id="search">
        <fieldset>
            <div>
                {{ form.genus(placeholder="Genus") }}
            </div>
            <div>
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
            </div>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</div>
{% if images %}
                {% for filename in images %}
                         <div>
                             {{ filename }}
                         </div>
                {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you show your full route function, please?

Comment: Edited to show full route funtion.

Comment: I've followed it through with the debugger and it definitely behaves as I expect it to, passes the list of images through to the template as the variable images and the images variable shows up in the debugger but then it just doesn't render anything inside the {% if images %} block.

Comment: This should definetly work. I guess your image list is empty. Try passing a list by hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add `return` to this line:

```
return render_template('results.html', form=form, images=images)
```

and the template should like this:

```
{% if images %}
    {% for filename in images %}
        <div>
          <img src="{{ filename }}">
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```